# Google Analytics real-time visitors amount is never correct

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-analytics

I have a page that is tracked using Google Analytics `chat.php`, the code snippet is in the correct place on the page as per the documentation.

This page has a Flash object that connects to a chat room via IRC. The chat room currently has 50 users in it thus all 50 users are currently on `chat.php`. The users are all unique as in 50 users connecting from 50 IP addresses.

Real-time visitors amount currently shows 7. Clearly this is incorrect. Why is this, what is the algorithm that is used here? Is it once an IP address stays on the same page for a certain duration of time then they drop out of the real-time visitors amount?

Answer (score 1):

Real time view only shows action for the last half hour and since one does not call new pages while one is  in a chat no new page views are registered and the user slips from real time view (Google Analytics does not use IP Adresses to track users, it uses a client id that is generated via the javascript tracking code or supplied by the website).

I'm not sure if the 30 minutes limit for real time view is fixed or tied to the session length - with Universal Analytics you might try to change the setting for the length of a tracking session in the property settings and see if that affects real time view (probably not, but changing the setting won't hurt in any case, since presumably session length for chat visitors will be more than 30 minutes. At the default value a one hour chat on chat.php will be counted as two visits).